# Fitbit Web API error grant type

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, fitbit

following is the error reported by api

```
{"errors":[
   {
     "errorType": "invalid_request",
     "message": "Missing 'grant_type' parameter value."
   }
], "success": false}
```

---

```
//curl request to fetch token with use of auth code used in my code

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,

CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  'Authorization:Basic'.base64_encode(FITBIT_CLIENT_ID.':'.FITBIT_CLIENT_SECRET),
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
),
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'code' => $auth_code,
    'client_id' => FITBIT_CLIENT_ID,
    'grant_type' => "authorization_code", //auth code received in url params
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/auth/fitbit/success'
)
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

i am receiving this error.  plz help to identify where could be the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your post field's array with to make sure you are doing the encoding (in case special characters).

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query (array(
...
))
```

Try putting a space between Authorization header. Standard one to use `Authorization: Basic`

If still seeing error then use VERBOSE mode with your curl request. And update your question with that verbose output so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes, when we give postfields input as string instead of array! It works fine. So http_build_query will solve the problem.                                                              THANKS